# R ggplot2: join two sections of a line graph together

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to join two sections of a line graph together in `ggplot`, but I don't know the right code.

Dataset:

```
Life_stage2 Year    d15N2
A   2002.5  1
A   2002    2
A   2001.5  4
A   2001    6
A   2000.5  5
A   2000    NA
A   1999.5  9
A   1999    2
A   1998.5  3
A   1998    4
B   1997.5  7
B   1997    8
C   1996    5
C   1995    6
C   1994.5  7
C   1994    2
```

My code:

```
nmmaps<-read.csv("testing.csv", as.is=T)

ggplot(nmmaps, aes(Year, d15N2, colour=factor(Life_stage2), group=Life_stage2)) +
                   geom_point() +
                   geom_line()
```

[image]

Basically, I want there to be

1. a gap between 1999.5 and 2000.5, but not between 1996 and 1997 and 1997.5 and 1998.
2. The colour of the line for the 1996-97 gap should be same colour as section prior to 1996 and 1997.5-98 gap should be same colour as section after 1998.

What code do I need to use to make this happen? Or alternatively, can I just add something into the data sheet to make **R** think there is data there?

**DATA**

```
nmmaps <- 
structure(list(Life_stage2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2002.5, 2002, 2001.5, 
2001, 2000.5, 2000, 1999.5, 1999, 1998.5, 1998, 1997.5, 1997, 
1996, 1995, 1994.5, 1994), d15N2 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 5L, NA, 
9L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L)), .Names = c("Life_stage2", 
"Year", "d15N2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L
))
```

Comment: Question is unclear because gap logic is not well-defined. Dataset also somewhat contradicts what you are describing.

Comment: This works but is ugly - but perhaps gives a way to progress: the idea is to use repeated `geom_line` calls to overwrite sections of the lines in different colours. `nmmaps$tag <- cut(nmmaps$Year, c(0,1997, 1997.5, Inf)) `

`ggplot(nmmaps, aes(Year, d15N2, colour=factor(Life_stage2))) +
  geom_line(colour="#F8766D") +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(group=tag)) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually best to change the data, so it becomes easy to plot. You can leave the plotting command as it is now, you just have to add two rows to the data.

```
df <- rbind(data.frame(Life_stage2 = c('C', 'A'), 
                       Year = c(1997, 1997.5), 
                       d15N2 = c(8, 7)), 
            nmmaps)

ggplot(df, aes(Year, d15N2, colour=Life_stage2)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```